# protobuf does not deserialize object corrctly

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have three classes:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Message
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int MethodId { set; get; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public CustomArgs Arguments { set; get; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class CustomArgs
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int IntVal { set; get; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string StrVal { set; get; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public CycleData Cd { set; get; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class CycleData
{
[ProtoMember(1)]
public int Id { set; get; }
[ProtoMember(2, AsReference = true)]
public CycleData Owner { set; get; }}
```

So when I create objects then serialize and deserialize it the `Arguments` property stay `null` but orignal object have a value. The sample code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CycleData cd = new CycleData()
    {
        Id = 5
    };
    cd.Owner = cd;

    CustomArgs a = new CustomArgs()
    {
        IntVal = 5,
        StrVal = "string",
        Cd = cd
    };

    Message oldMsg = new Message()
    {
        MethodId = 3,
        Arguments = a
    };

    Stream st = new MemoryStream();
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(st, oldMsg);
    var newMsg = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Message>(st);

}
```

So `newMsg.Arguments` is null after deserialize. What i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple error.  Once you serialize/write to the memstream, the `.Pointer` remain at the end of the stream.  Deserializing immediately after using on the same stream fails because there is nothing to read after that point.  Just reset it:

```
using (Stream st = new MemoryStream())
{ 
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(st, oldMsg);
    st.Position = 0;          // point to start of stream
    var newMsg = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Message>(st);
}
```

I also put the stream in a using block to dispose of it.